# no muestra el valor de los value en console.log

Tags: angularjs

Estoy intentando obtener el `value` de un grupo de `option`,  el cual funciona perfectamente en el navegador, aquí el ejemplo en [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9aIJP53BuX9wv2OObnBI?p=preview), pero al compilar el mismo código para probarlo en un dispositivo móvil, sigue apareciendo el `value` en la vista, pero no aparece en el `console.log();`, me dice que el valor es `undefined`

### grupos.html

```
<div class="list">

        <label class="item item-input item-select">

            <div class="input-label">
                Grupos
            </div>              

            <select ng-change="datos.seleccionar()" 
                    ng-options="grupo.Codigo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos.menuGrupos track by grupo.Codigo" 
                    ng-model="seleccionado">
                 <option value="">Seleccione un grupo</option>
            </select>   

        </label>

        <h3 class="item">{{seleccionado}}</h3>

    </div>
```

### grupos.js

```
mostrarGruposProf.$inject = ['$scope'];

function mostrarGruposProf($scope) {

    var getGrupos, infoGrupos;

    getGrupos = localStorage.getItem('GruposProf');
    infoGrupos = JSON.parse(getGrupos);

    $scope.datos = {
        menuGrupos: infoGrupos,
        seleccionar: function() {
            console.log($scope.seleccionado);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No he podido reproducir exactamente el problema que tienes pero creo que el error que te puede estar pasando es que estas usando **`track by`** en conjunto con **`select as`** lo cual usualmente no es una buena idea porque es muy propenso a generar errores. Citando la doc de angular

> Ten cuidado cuando uses select as y track by en la misma expresión.

Esto no significa que no se pueda usar sino que debes tener mucho cuidado con esta combinación.

Mirando tu expresión

```
grupo.Codigo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos.menuGrupos track by grupo.Codigo
```

Esto usará `grupo.Codigo` como el valor asociado a `ng-model` pero a su vez **`track by`** intentará usar el objeto como tal `grupo` para llevar la cuenta de cual es el seleccionado. Esto es lo que hace que no se seleccione el elemento como tal en el primer caso del ejemplo que te pongo debajo.

Para solucionarlo simplemente cámbialo a

```
// Sin track by (recomendado)
grupo.Codigo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos.menuGrupos
```

o

```
// Sin especificar una propiedad en el select as
grupo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos.menuGrupos track by grupo.Codigo
```

Este es un demo de tu problema original, una muestra de porque el select no funciona y las dos soluciones para que puedas compararlas

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

mostrarGruposProf.$inject = ['$scope'];

app.controller('MainCtrl', mostrarGruposProf);

function mostrarGruposProf($scope) {

  var getGrupos, infoGrupos;

  //getGrupos = localStorage.getItem('GruposProf');
  //infoGrupos = JSON.parse(getGrupos);
  infoGrupos = [{
    Codigo: 1,
    Nombre: 'Grupo1'
  }, {
    Codigo: 2,
    Nombre: 'Grupo2'
  }, {
    Codigo: 3,
    Nombre: 'Grupo3'
  }, {
    Codigo: 4,
    Nombre: 'Grupo4'
  }];

  $scope.datos = {
    menuGrupos: infoGrupos,
    seleccionar: function() {
      console.log($scope.seleccionado);
    }
  };

  $scope.datos1 = {
    menuGrupos: infoGrupos,
    seleccionar: function() {
      console.log($scope.seleccionado1);
    }
  };

  $scope.datos2 = {
    menuGrupos: infoGrupos,
    seleccionar: function() {
      console.log($scope.seleccionado2);
    }
  };

  $scope.datos3 = {
    menuGrupos: infoGrupos,
    seleccionar: function() {
      console.log($scope.seleccionado3);
    }
  };

  $scope.seleccionado3 = infoGrupos[2];

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    Versión con problemas
    <select ng-change="datos.seleccionar()" ng-options="grupo.Codigo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos.menuGrupos track by grupo.Codigo" ng-model="seleccionado">
      <option value="">Seleccione un grupo</option>
    </select>
    {{seleccionado}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    Solución 1
    <select ng-change="datos1.seleccionar()" ng-options="grupo.Codigo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos1.menuGrupos" ng-model="seleccionado1">
      <option value="">Seleccione un grupo</option>
    </select>
    {{seleccionado1}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    Solución 2
    <select ng-change="datos2.seleccionar()" ng-options="grupo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos2.menuGrupos track by grupo.Codigo" ng-model="seleccionado2">
      <option value="">Seleccione un grupo</option>
    </select>
    {{seleccionado2}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    Síntoma de porque no funciona
    <select ng-change="datos3.seleccionar()" ng-options="grupo.Codigo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos3.menuGrupos track by grupo.Codigo" ng-model="seleccionado3">
      <option value="">Seleccione un grupo</option>
    </select>
    {{seleccionado3}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Bueno la forma que tu recomiendas, osea esta  `grupo.Codigo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos.menuGrupos`, muestra el codigo del grupo en la vista, pero no en el console, y usando esta solucion `grupo as grupo.Nombre for grupo in datos.menuGrupos track by grupo.Codigo`, me muestra en la vista el **JSON** completo, y en console sale undefined.